# AVPlayerItem seekToTime memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, avfoundation, avplayer

I have 4 views where I play 1-2 second videos in a loop, using AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification like this:

```
- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [notification object];
    [playerItem seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
}
```

When I looked at Activity Monitor instrument, I noticed a continuous 10 kB/s memory leak. If I comment the seekToTime call, the leak is gone.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238429/why-cant-i-rely-on-nsnotificationcenter-using-avfoundation-to-loop-video ?

Comment: No, I also use AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone. My problem is the memory leak anyway, looping works fine.

Comment: Did you ever make progress here?

Comment: I don't remember and I can't find out, sorry.